# access raspi ssh from internet

Tags: ssh, router, raspberry-pi

This is my setting:

A modem/router provided by my ISP (external static IP)
My own router with all my network  that is connected to the modem/router

I can ssh to the raspi locally.

My approach:
open port 22 in isp router and redirect it to external ip of my router. 
Open port 22 in my router and redirect it to raspi ip

but that doesnt work...

```
     |
     |
  external ip:22
  isp router
  192.168.1.1
     |
     |
  192.168.1.100
  my router
  192.168.0.1
     |
     |
  192.168.0.42
  raspi
```

my rules

```
isp router: TCP 192.168.1.100 22 22    
my router:  TCP 192.168.0.42  22 22
```

In my head it seems all ok
Putty says network error: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

Only to rule out the obvious:
Is your 'my router' providing NAT or are all IP addresses pulled from your 'ISP router'?

If all IP addresses are pulled from your 'ISP router', what subnet mask do you use'? If your 'my router' is providing NAT, then your subnet mask is irrelevant.

Comment: 'my router' is providing NAT. (there's also dynamic routing mode, witch I'm not familiar with) the model of 'my router' is linksys  EA6900 if that helps in any way

Answer (score 0):

By default the Raspberry Pi is running a firewall which blocks connections originating on a subnet to which it is not attached.

These rules are in `/etc/network/if-up.d/secure-srm` (they may be in another file if you are running a different image).

You need to add a rule here to allow the ssh connection.